# Cannot remove EventListener when 'mouseout' occurs

Tags: javascript, keypress, keydown, mouseleave, event-listener

I don't know why I can't remove `EventListener` when `mouseout` event occurs.
I want to activate `EventListener('keydown')`, when one table row is hovered. The reason is I want to use "delete" key, to remove hovered row, when it's hovered.
I assume problem can be caused by the fact, that `keydown` event is attached to `document` not certain element on which it's done. However isn't it impossible to add it to certain element?

```
    var table = document.querySelector('tbody');
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row, showHide) 
            {
                return function() 
                { 
                    console.log('showHide ',showHide);
                    if (showHide === 'hover' )
                    {
                        document.addEventListener('keydown' ,function(ev)
                        {
                            if (showHide == 'hover')
                            {
                                console.log('hover target ', ev.target);
                            }
                        },false);
                        return;
                    }

                    else if (showHide === 'leave')
                    {
                        document.removeEventListener('keydown' ,function(ev)
                        {
                            if (ev.target && showHide === 'leave')
                            {
                                console.log('out ',ev);
                            }

                        },false);                           
                        console.log('left');
                    }
                 };
            };
        currentRow.addEventListener('mouseover', createClickHandler(currentRow, 'hover'), false);
        currentRow.addEventListener('mouseout', createClickHandler(currentRow, 'leave'), false);
    }
```

**_______________________________________**

**[EDIT]**

I think i solved my problem, but code seems too long and little bit too many those `EventListener`'s as for kind of simple solution.

Can somebody tell me how to **make this code shorter**, please...?

```
var table = document.querySelector('tbody');
        var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row, showHide) 
            {
                return function() 
                { 
                    var delKey = function(ev)
                    {
                        console.log('hover target ', ev.target);
                    };

                    console.log('showHide ',showHide);
                    if (showHide === 'hover' )
                    {
                        //console.log('hovered ',row);

                        document.addEventListener('keydown' ,delKey,false);
                        document.addEventListener('keyup' ,function(){
                            document.removeEventListener('keydown',delKey,false);
                            console.log('removed event ');
                        },false);

                        document.body.addEventListener('click', function()
                        {
                            document.removeEventListener('keydown', delKey, false);
                        },false);
                    }

                    else if (showHide === 'leave')
                    {
                        console.log('hidden ');
                    }
                };
            };
        currentRow.addEventListener('mouseover', createClickHandler(currentRow, 'hover'), false);
        currentRow.addEventListener('mouseout', createClickHandler(currentRow, 'leave'), false);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[`EventTarget.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) should be called with the listener added with `addEventListener`, not with a new function. You're essentially telling `document` to remove a listener that has never been added.

Do it this way:

```js
var listener = document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { ... });
document.removeEventListener('keydown', listener);
```

---

**Edit:** working example

```js
var table = document.querySelector('tbody');
var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
var log = document.getElementById('log');

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var currentRow = table.rows[i];
  var createClickHandler = function(row, showHide) {
    return function() {
      var listener;
      
      console.log('showHide ',showHide);
      if (showHide === 'hover') {
        listener = document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
          if (showHide == 'hover') {
            console.log('hover target ', ev.target);
          }
        }, false);
        return;
      } else if (showHide === 'leave') {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', listener, false);                           
        console.log('left');
      }
    };
  };
  currentRow.addEventListener('mouseover', createClickHandler(currentRow, 'hover'), false);
  currentRow.addEventListener('mouseout', createClickHandler(currentRow, 'leave'), false);
}

// don't do that -- only for demo purposes
console.log = function() { log.innerHTML = log.innerHTML + '<br>' + [].slice.call(arguments).join(' '); };
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, but where should I execute `removeEventListener`? When i added it just like you showed (after listener), it doesn't work. I tried to put it inside `listener` but it also doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/at1ZGwzV

Comment: See my updated answer. It's just a start based on your example, you may have to alter it to suit your needs.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't turn off `keydown` event when mouse is out of element. So even if `mouseout` event is executed, it still listening to `keydown` event, which i don't want to.
I want `keydown` event to be executed only when `mouseover` is active. When mouse is off element `keydown` should NOT be executed.

Comment: As I said: It's a start to show how to remove event listeners. Making it suit your needs is left as an exercise ;) .

Comment: Why if i `console.log(listener)`, it says `undefined`, wherever i place this console.log?

Comment: `listener` is undefined and i think that's why `removeEventListener` doesn't work for `keydown` event. **CODE** http://pastebin.com/ACL8k8qD